# MS Office Word how to add a customer ribbon and also appear in other computer?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I am trying to create a word template(.dot, or .dotx), and add some buttons with call macro. I find it word in my own computer. But when the word template open in another computer, the ribbon is not exist.

I find that the office support stated that the customize ribbon can be "share" with using export and export ribbon: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-ribbon-in-office-00f24ca7-6021-48d3-9514-a31a460ecb31

But I do not like this method as when I pass this document to other user/client, they may not know how to do this step.

So, does anyone know how to create a customize ribbon and can be open by other computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Custom UI Editor tool, which helps you to create the custom XML and callbacks you insert into your template. A zip file containing the tool can be downloaded from the [OpenXMLDeveloper.org](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2006/05/26/customuieditor.aspx) website.

The website is shutdown, no active postings are taking place on it, but you still can read about the tool and download it from there.

Comment: Thank you Michaels. I find that the MS Office 2003 can add the button individually in the file. But this behavior has been changed in 2007 or later that using customize ribbon to maintance. But this can only using "Share" method to copy the ribbon's toolbars into other computers.

I find more information from below URL:
https://forums.windowssecrets.com/showthread.php/133827-Converting-Office-2003-toolbars-to-2010-Ribbon
under ron007's reply, he/she had a deep information about the customize ribbon information. And I finally using Custom UI Editor tool for my working file.

Thanks again!